# JQuery - Adding change event to dropdown

Tags: jquery

The underlying HTML for my drop down has a chance of changing and I was trying to set it up using the `.live` option rather than the `.change` option.   it does not work for me.

What I currently have is:

```
$("#ItemsPerPage").change(function(e) { return updatePaging(); });
```

Unfortuantely, if I update this control via `$.ajax` it loses the event definition.  What I tried, and is not working, is:

```
$("#ItemsPerPage").live("change", function(e) { return updatePaging(); });
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of rebinding the `<select>` every time, you're better off just swapping its contents (the list of `<option>` elements) instead.

So use this as you already are:

```
$("#ItemsPerPage").change(function(e) { return updatePaging(); });
```

but when you update it, just swap out its contents ( where `newSelectElement` is the new `<select>` element):

```
function updateItemsPerPage( newSelectElement ) {
    $("#ItemsPerPage").empty().append( newSelectElement.childNodes );
}
```

This way, the binding won't need to be refreshed because the node itself isn't swapped.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on samiz's suggestion, you would need to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    bind_items_per_page();
});

function bind_items_per_page() {
    $("#ItemsPerPage").unbind('change').bind('change',function() { 
        updatePaging(); 
    });
}

function updatePaging() {
    $.post('/some/script',{foo:'bar',bar:'foo'},function(data) {
        /* what ever you need to do */
        // And assuming what ever you did above changed your select box...
        bind_items_per_page();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The change event is not supported by live(). How about running a function at the end of every AJAX call that reassigns the event definition?